# Only submit AJAX form if the variable is true

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

```
$(function () {
  $('#submit').submit(function() {

    var isValid = document.getElementById("form-setting").checkValidity();

    var data = {};
    data.id = $("#id").val();
    data.title = $("#title").val();
    data.content = $("#content").val();
    data.author = $("#author").val();
    data.email = $("#email").val();

    if (isValid) {

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: '/admin/setting',
      success: function (data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    });
    }
  });
});
```

So I have the above code where I will get all the value of the field that filled by the user, and only send the object to the node.js server if everything is filled and validated.

The problem here is that if I have that `isValid` check there is nothing being sent to the server at all.

In fact there is no action happens inside that `if` statement at all because I tried put some `alert` in there and nothing is showing at all.

Comment: and what is `checkValidity()` ?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `checkValidity` since it's not implemented on all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prevent default behaviour of your form's submit handler:

```
$(function () {
    $('#submit').submit(function (e) {

        var isValid = document.getElementById("form-setting").checkValidity();
        alert(isValid); //<<< ALERT HERE
        var data = {};
        data.id = $("#id").val();
        data.title = $("#title").val();
        data.content = $("#content").val();
        data.author = $("#author").val();
        data.email = $("#email").val();

        if (isValid) {
            alert('PASS'); //<<< ALERT HERE
            $.ajax({
                context: this, //use for success callback
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: '/admin/setting',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    //this.submit();  //uncomment this line if you want to submit form
                }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

});

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear, but if you check line #13 it never enters the block of checking `isValid` at all :(

Comment: I think the problem is that the checkValidity is only work with the GET method :(

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isValid) {
  // send your ajax call
  return false; // plus don't want your form being submited since you allready submited it through ajax 
}
else{
  return false; // since you want to prevent the submission
}
```

But a better option would be to not use form at all, and add a listener on a simple button

Comment: I used `return false` to prevent submission but it may be that you have to call `e.preventDefault();` to do so. (I'm not sure)

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear, but if you check line #13 it never enters the block of checking `isValid` at all :(

Comment: @roasted it returns true for me

Comment: What is this function checkValidity()? BTW, you should show how you are trying to debug it, because is isValid is true, the condition if(...) is reached, i think you debug it wrong

Comment: OP is doing something wrong for sure. And sorry, made a mistake i would comment below my answer, not yours